# Does Weblogic interrupt long running threads

Tags: java, weblogic

I have a MQEvent  Listener thread which continuously polls MQ for new messages and processes them. This application is deployed to a clustered Weblogic Environment. Once the application runs for a few months,the listener threads on all of the Weblogic Managed Servers are getting interrupted(at almost the same time) resulting in the listener being terminated. I have to redeploy the application to make this work again.

I'm not able to find anything which is interrupting the thread. The Listener uses multiple

Thread.sleep() calls but I'm not sure how the Listener is getting interrupted.

```
  public void run() {
    while (!isInterrupted()) {
     //keep processing messages and sleep
     }
}
```

Does Weblogic interrupt long running threads and try to shut them down?

Comment: It could be a force-shutdown request from the admin server for some reason. Check the logs.

Comment: logs tell me that there were multiple stuck threads(not this one,it has the stacktrace). - "ExecuteThread: '56' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "669" seconds working on the request"

Comment: did your server status changed to critical? (when you had multiple stuck threads)

Comment: no it didn't. It was all normal.